# Ruby on Rails Where clause less than greater than

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I want to do a ruby on rails query that is structured this way with a less than and greater than constraint.

```
self.order('random()')
  .where(
    friends: friend,
    age: {minimum: 5, maximum: 20}
  )
```

The above is how I imagine it to be done, being a ruby beginner. However this does not work.
How can this be correctly achieved?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a range object.

```
.where(age: 5..50)
```

Or you could write

```
.where('age BETWEEN 5 AND 20')
```

Comment: AHH!! Ruby, just when I thouhgt you couldn't be any more elegant. THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

You can use operator also

```
.where("id >= ? and id <=  ?",5,20)
```